# How do I printf a date in C?

Tags: c, date, ctime

I'm trying to print a date from a string like "01/01/01" and get something like "Monday First January 2001.

I found something with the man of ctime but really don't get it how to use it.

Any help ?

Thanks,

Comment: Share what you found please

Comment: Actually, pretty much nothing just about mans.
Just understood that there is a structure with that we can fill.. But Don't know how. Struct is "struct tm timep"

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Development/PrintlocalandUTCtime.htm
See this link it may help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `strptime` to convert your string date to `struct tm`

```
struct tm tm;
strptime("01/26/12", "%m/%d/%y", &tm);
```

And then print `struct tm` in the appropriate date format with `strftime`

```
char str_date[256];
strftime(str_date, sizeof(str_date), "%A, %d %B %Y", &tm);
printf("%s\n", str_date);
```

Answer (score 5):

[`strftime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) does the job.

```
char buffer[256] = "";
{
  struct tm t = <intialiser here>;
  strftime(buffer, 256, "%H/%M/%S", &t);
}
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: The signature of `strftime` is `size_t strftime(char *s, size_t max, const char *format, const struct tm *tm);`. You're missing the `size_t` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [strftime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html)