# Convert date stored as 1912.02.14 to printf as February 2, 1912

Tags: c

These two links have been helpful thus far:

- [How do I printf a date in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161818/how-do-i-printf-a-date-in-c)
- [Compiler gets warnings when using strptime function (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334558/compiler-gets-warnings-when-using-strptime-function-c)

But I cannot quite get there yet. Using the info from the two links above, I can get their sample to work nicely:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct tm tm;
   char str_date[256];

   strptime("01/26/12", "%m/%d/%y", &tm);
   strftime(str_date, sizeof(str_date), "%A, %d %B %Y", &tm);
   printf("%s\n", str_date);

   return 0;
}
```

This returns "Thursday, 26 January 2012" on my console which is correct.

All good so far.

However, everything I have tried with the date in yyyy.mm.dd format in `strptime` gives me this on the console "?, 00 ? 2019"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct tm tm;
   char str_date[256];

   strptime("1912.02.14", "%y.%m.%d", &tm);
   strftime(str_date, sizeof(str_date), "%A, %d %B %Y", &tm);
   printf("%s\n", str_date);

   return 0;
}
```

If I can get `strptime` to work correctly, I can juggle around the format specifiers in `strftime` to get the output I want.

ANSWER: Thanks to BladeMight's help, this code works very well for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
char *strptime(const char *buf, const char *format, struct tm *tm);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct tm tm;
   char str_date[256];

   strptime("1912.02.14", "%Y.%m.%d", &tm);
   strftime(str_date, sizeof(str_date), "%B %d, %Y", &tm);
   printf("%s\n", str_date);

   return 0;
 }
```

If I leave out:

```
char *strptime(const char *buf, const char *format, struct tm *tm);
```

Then I get compiler errors:

```
78.c: In function ‘main’:
78.c:11:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strptime’; did you  mean ‘strftime’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 strptime("1912.02.14", "%Y.%m.%d", &tm);
 ^~~~~~~~
 strftime
```

If I add the two defines mentioned in the answer of the 2nd link I posted at the top then I can leave out the definition of strptime.

I still had an issue with 1 digit days either displaying with a leading zero or leading space in my final output regardless of what formatting I tried.  In the end, I just wrote my own function to take care of this.

I appreciate everyone's help as I learned quite a bit on this issue.

Comment: Two-digits years are different from four-digit years. Use `%Y` on the second example.

Comment: Look at POSIX [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) — note that it returns a value, and check what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format of Year differs, so you should use another format, the `%Y` instead of `%y`, code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
char *strptime(const char *buf, const char *format, struct tm *tm);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct tm tm;
   char str_date[256];

   strptime("1912.02.14", "%Y.%m.%d", &tm);
   strftime(str_date, sizeof(str_date), "%A, %d %B %Y", &tm);
   printf("%s\n", str_date);

   return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Wednesday, 14 February 1912
```

Comment: `char *strptime(const char *buf, const char *format, struct tm *tm);` is superfluous as its prototype is contained in `time.h`.

Comment: @BladeMight.  Thanks for your help!  With very minor tweaking of the date format in strftime, it outputs exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Strange, when I tried compiling without this line gcc gives me error that it is not declared.

Comment: You need to `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` **before** you include the header files. See [strptime(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) **Note:** the comment `/* See feature_test_macros(7) */`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the info, didn't know that.